# Favicon doesn't appear but the image can be opened

Tags: html, css

This code `< link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="{$BASEURL}/favicon.ico"/>`
supposed to show favicons on the tab, but it doesn't.
I tried to inspect element, then open link in new tab, the image is there.

What are the possible causes?
Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried clearing your cache?

Comment: i did , but it doesn't seem to appear. I have also tried incognito mode@NikosGatzoulis

Comment: Do you try this in your localhost or in the production server? Try pushing it to production and clearing your cache.

Comment: @NikosGatzoulis : This is in production server

Answer (score 0):

try it another browser that you have not used in testing it before.

then try clearing your cache. It has happened to me many times.

Comment: He already mentioned that clearing cache doesn't work and I am sure he tried to use another browser.

Comment: Hm..
Okay, i missed out this step..
It is showing in safari.
The one that didn't show up is chrome..

Comment: ok change the name of the favicon file. Then check it  if it will work on chrome.

Comment: I did..
Nothing happen as well..
This is weird

Comment: wait for a while then refresh the browser it should be ok.